# Javascript:Change class and title on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

On clicking the number should change the class and title from not_viewed to viewed making
color change from red to green .But obviously,it is not working as no color change is occuring.

Html

```
<span title="not_viewed" class="not_viewed" id="1" onclick="javascript:changeclass()">1</span>
```

```
Javascript
```

```
function changeclass() {var NAME = document.getElementById("1"); NAME.className = "viewed" NAME.title="viewed"
  < /script>
}
```

css

```
span.viewed{color:green; }
span.not_viewed{color:red;}
span{cursor:pointer;}
```

See
http://jsfiddle.net/yKbFk/1/

Comment: How to vote down this more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `< /script>` tag from function.

Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/yKbFk/6/

Comment: just write the </script> outside the function `changeclass()`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `< /script>` from within the function, because it's causing a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4U9J/1/)

Remember to check the console (F12) for errors to make debugging easier for yourself.